# Correct syntax for initialization of a pointer to an array

Tags: c, pointers

How can I initialize pointer to an array in C correctly

Here is my code

```
int (*data[10]);
int a[10];
data = &a[0]; /* gives a warning "int *" cannot be assigned to entity of "int (*)[10]" */
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: It would be `int (*data)[10]`.`int (*data[10])` is no different from `int *data[10]`

Comment: I would use `int **date;` so if the size of the array will have to change it won't required two changes

Comment: I was about to answer this question.But backed out when I saw three heavyweights of SO answering.

Answer (score 6):

1. Declare a pointer to an array correctly:

   ```
   int (*data)[10];
   ```
2. Assign a pointer to an array to it:

   ```
   int a[10];
   data = &a;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your parenthesis are wrong. You need:

```
int (*data)[10];
```

Note that you can use [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) to get help with these things.

For your original code it says:

> declare data as array 10 of pointer to int

For mine it says:

> declare data as pointer to array 10 of int

Answer (score 1):

The variable `data` is an array of pointer, and you try to assign to it a single pointer. If you want to declare `data` as a pointer to an array you have to re-arrange the parentheses:

```
int (*data)[10];
```

I recommend you read about the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
int **data;
int a[10];
data = &a;
```

you can define data as other suggested: `int (*date)[10];`
but i believe that using it as a double pointer will make more seance the day you wish to change the size of that array from 10 to anything else !

Comment: This code does not compile cleanly because  `&a[0]` is an `int *` being assigned to an `int **`.